# How do I automatically remove anvils in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm creating a Minecraft PVP map where players can purchase enchanted weapons for XP. However, I'm supplying certain items in my shop that I do not want players to repair with anvils (e.g. A "Sniper Bow" which insta-kills players with a remaining durability of 10 shots). How can I make a mechanism in ***vanilla*** Minecraft to automatically remove anvils once placed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the total cost to repair an item is greater than 39, it cannot be repaired in survival mode. You can use the `RepairCost` nbt tag to make it too expensive to repair an item in an anvil. For example, this command will spawn a Power 10 bow that cannot be repaired with an anvil:

```
/give @p minecraft:bow 1 374 {ench:[{id:48,lvl:10}],RepairCost:40}
```

Comment: Great, this solves ratchet-freaks's problem of preventing fast players and server lag ;)

Answer (score 6):

Set a command block with a comparator clock that runs:

```
/clear @a minecraft:anvil
```

This will always clear out any anvils any player has in their inventory.  The player won't get the items back, but it should be punishment for making an anvil

Comment: @zeldarulez this only removes them from player inventories, a fast player may be able to outspeed the timer, but a too fast timer may bog down the server

Comment: @ratchetfreak I don't think anyone will be fast enough to beat a 2-tick clock.  Anyways, I think this is the best you can do without hundreds of command blocks testing for anvil blocks and removing them.